# Scripting for Facebook AR Studio AudioModule

Tags: facebook, augmented-reality

I've been playing around with Facebook AR but I'm not sure how to script using the AudioModule. The tutorial in facebook's page only explains on using the patch editor but i want to know how to script it as well.

Basically, the audio plays only when a video texture is playing. The video texture only plays after a timeout of 10secs, so the audio should follow suit. Obviously, its `sound.play()` but how do i get the audio itself?

I have a speaker -> audio : playback_controller_model0

Does using AudioModule require anything? like `var Audio = require("Audio");` ?

i did something like :

```
var Audio = require("Audio");
var sound = Audio.getPlayBackController("playback_controller_model0");
sound.play();
```

and it doesn't seem to be working though because the video texture script is being ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Facebook recently removed the option to script audio playback in favor or using the Patch Editor to control audio playback. As of the latest version you can only use the Patch Editor to play audio, God knows why... But, you **can** use the [script to patches bridge](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ar-studio/docs/visual-programming/javascript-to-patch-bridging/) to trigger playback via script, by sending messages to the playback controller in your Patch from script.

Like so in script:

```
Patches.setPulseValue('PlayMySound', Reactive.once());
```

And in the Patches Editor:
[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Ahh.. That's new! Thank you! Will try this out.

Comment: Cool, if it works for you, I would appreciate an upvote on the answer, thanks :)